# how to uninstall server 2008 R2 features

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, uninstall

my friend told me : ***{I cant uninstall any features that you install it to win server,For example he installed web server to win server but he could not remove it anymore}.***

is it possible to unable uninstall features after i install it?

how can i do that?

he installed the standard edition of windows server 2008 r2

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can remove features. You'll need to go to Server Manager, Expand the "Features" tab and then use the Add/Remove Features buttons on the right-hand side. IIS, though, your *web server* is a role rather than a feature.

For how to install server roles, have a look at [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283014%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible - corrupt windows installs are always possible.

It also is possible he has no rights to remove it on the account he uses.

But otherwise - no, features can be added and removed.